# sqlite3 with cursor execute intergrity error

Tags: database, sqlite, sqldatatypes

Why isn't my sql3 working?

```
cursor.execute('''

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students(

studentid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
forename VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
currentgrade VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
targetgrade VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)
''')

cursor.execute('''
INSERT INTO students(studentid,forename,surname,currentgrade,targetgrade)
VALUES ("a","b","1","c","d");
''')

db.commit()
```

This is the error it is throwing:

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: sqlite3 error]

Comment: It looks like `studentid` is expecting an integer and receiving a string: 'a'.

Comment: You should include the relevant code and error messages as text in the question. People are more willing to help when what they need is in the question, and it makes the question searchable.

Comment: Also, your table has 5 columns, but you are supplying 6 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"datatype mismatch" means you're trying to assign a value to a column with a type that doesn't match the type of the value. In this case, `studentid` is defined with type `INTEGER`, but you're trying to insert the value `"a"`, which is a string, or `VARCHAR`.

Try something like this instead:

```
cursor.execute('''
INSERT INTO students(studentid,forename,surname,currentgrade,targetgrade)
VALUES (1,"b","1","c","d");
''')
```